# Arranging hidden elements using CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**OK, this is what I need :**

- I've got a horizontal container (let's call that C), containing 2 elements (A,B)
- Of these two elements, only one has to be visible at any time. So, the other's `visibility` property is set to `hidden`.
- Let's say these elements are placed with this exact sequence : `|<----------- A B ->|`, and thus right-aligned.
- When element B is active, everything is OK.
- When element A is active (and thus B is invisible), the A element doesn't float to the right side and remains where it is : `|<----------- A --->|`

**The question :**

- How can I "push" element A to the right ("above" element B), so that it is like it's floating right/

Comment: Would you be able to set up a JS fiddle showcasing the situation?

Comment: `visibility:hidden` makes element invisible but it still occupies the same space as if it is visible. You should hide `B` with `display:none` so `A` will float to the right (if you use CSS floats).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `display:none;` instead of `visibility:hidden;` as `visibility:hidden;` will hide the element but still occupy the space

Comment: Great answer buddy! Thanks a lot - you can't imagine how much time of hair-pulling you've saved me! Trying to be fair, since this one was the first answer, this one is going to be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

`Visibility: hidden` will prevent the element from being rendered, but it will still take up space.

`Display: none` will prevent the element from being rendered AND from affecting the layout.

Comment: @JanDvorak +1 for explaining it better mate :)

Comment: @JanDvorak The only reason for that was I answered a bit earlier than you mate.